# PostgreSQL: Create Database, Table and populate data in a single SQL script file

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm trying to create a database and add create a table in a single SQL script:

```
CREATE DATABASE w3;

CREATE TABLE w3.public.examples (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    text VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO
    w3.public.examples (text)
VALUES
    ('val1');

INSERT INTO
    w3.public.examples (text)
VALUES
    ('val2');

INSERT INTO
    w3.public.examples (text)
VALUES
    ('val3');

SELECT
    *
FROM
    w3.public.examples;
```

When I'm exucuting this script via psql: `psql -U postgres -a -f script.sql` I'm getting error:

> psql:script.sql:26: ERROR:  cross-database references are not implemented: "w3.public.examples"
>
> LINE 4:     w3.public.examples;

Does it mean I cannot create and use a database in a single SQL file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `CREATE DATABASE w3;` add `\c w3` then remove `w3.` references:

```
CREATE DATABASE w3;

-- connect to the newly created database
\c w3

CREATE TABLE public.examples (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    text VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO
    public.examples (text)
VALUES
    ('val1'), ('val2'), ('val3');

SELECT
    *
FROM
    public.examples;
```

Log:

```
$ psql
psql (12.2 (Ubuntu 12.2-2.pgdg18.04+1), server 11.7 (Ubuntu 11.7-2.pgdg18.04+1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# CREATE DATABASE w3;
CREATE DATABASE
postgres=# 
postgres=# -- connect to the newly created database
postgres=# \c w3
psql (12.2 (Ubuntu 12.2-2.pgdg18.04+1), server 11.7 (Ubuntu 11.7-2.pgdg18.04+1))
You are now connected to database "w3" as user "nd".
w3=# 
w3=# CREATE TABLE public.examples (
w3(#     id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
w3(#     text VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
w3(# );
CREATE TABLE
w3=# 
w3=# INSERT INTO
w3-#     public.examples (text)
w3-# VALUES
w3-#     ('val1'), ('val2'), ('val3');
INSERT 0 3
w3=# 
w3=# SELECT
w3-#     *
w3-# FROM
w3-#     public.examples;
 id | text 
----+------
  1 | val1
  2 | val2
  3 | val3
(3 rows)

w3=#
```

Comment: Thanks! Not it works.
By the way, I've tried \c earlier and received Syntax error. I guess it was because I added semicolon after the statement and thought it was \c statement error and I cannot use it there.

Comment: @VladMorzhanov It is not a statement but "metacommand" of the `psql` utility: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS. Thus it works in the `psql` only. I updated the answer with IO.

Comment: Note taht if your tables are created in the default schema 'public' you don't need to reference to them by dot notation, just remove the 'public.' part of your clauses